# How do I make a logo align to artboard as one object in adobe illustrator?

Tags: vector, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I have been working on this issue for days and have been trying different methods that I have found in similar questions on stackoverflow and other forums to make this work but can still not figure out what is keeping me from aligning the entire object as one in adobe illustrator.

I have grouped all of the objects and the objects are merged into one layer. I click Align in the control panel. Then I make sure Align to Artboard is selected. I also click on Transform to make sure the two boxes are unchecked. Then I click Align to center horizontal, everything moves accordingly. Then when I click Align to center vertically, the logo is altered. All I am trying to do is get the entire logo centered on the artboard.

Does anyone have an idea on what step I am missing to make the entire logo move as one object?

I didn't have enough reputation to post images so I provided the image links below.

Before: http://tinypic.com/r/fxyq1h/8

After: http://tinypic.com/r/2gui1ph/8

You can see that the smile is moved up a few pixels which is driving me crazy. I can resize the objects as one. I can move the objects as one.  But I can't align the objects to the center of the artboard as one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to active the guideline, but it's already activated.
You should see some tutorial one Adobe TV

Comment: Do you have a link to the tutorial I can watch?